# Finding bases for the eigenspaces of A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Find bases for the eigenspaces of A. I find the following eigenvalues:

$$\lambda_1 = 5$$
$$\lambda_2 = -1$$
$$\lambda_3 = 2$$

And solve for $I\lambda - A$ for each of the eigenvalues producing the following:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = ? \space \lambda = 5
$$

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} \lambda = 2
$$

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-3 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} \lambda = -1
$$

Each matrix has 1 free variable and I have calculated 2 of the bases, but I am finding it hard to get the last one. Can anyone help? The results I have found do not give valid vectors to diagonalize A with:
$$P^{-1}AP = D$$

Comment: You do not have the correct eigenvector for $\lambda=2$.  It is in fact an eigenvector for $\lambda=5$.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenspace of the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=5$ is the span of the vector $\vec v$ such that:
$$
(A-5I)\vec v= \vec 0
$$
that is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&3\\
0&-6&0\\
0&1&-3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\v_2\\v_3
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

this is equivalent to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
v_+3v_3=0\\
-6v_2=0\\
v_2-3v_3=0
\end{cases}
$$
that has solution $\vec v=[x,0,0]^T \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, so a possible eigenvector is $\vec \nu_1=[1,0,0]^T$

In the same way you can find the eigenspaces, and an aigenvector; for the other two eigenvalues:
$$
\lambda_2=2 \quad \rightarrow \quad \nu_2=[-1,0-1]^T
$$
$$
\lambda_3=-1 \quad \rightarrow \quad \nu_3=[0,-3,1]^T
$$

Comment: I see my mistake now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answers:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}  \lambda = 5
$$
Since $x_1$ is a free variable (no leading 1's in the first column).

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix} \lambda = 2
$$
Since $x_3$ is a free variable and $x_1 = -x_3$

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-3 \\
1
\end{bmatrix} \lambda = -1
$$

And finally $x_3$ is a free variable and $x_2 = -3x_3$

Verifying $P^{-1}AP = D$ where $P$ is the matrix consisting of the 3 basis vectors produces:

$$ D =
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$